# Factories: how to pass temporary smart pointers to functions. C++

Tags: c++, factory, smart-pointers, temporary

I have a class Foo

```
class Foo;
```

a factory returning a pointer to it:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> createFoo();
```

and, since I have been told by [Herb](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) that a plain function with no special claim on the lifetime of Foo should take plain naked pointers:

```
void plainf(Foo* f);
```

How is my client supposed to correctly do this?

```
plainF(createFoo());
```

He would not be happy if he had to write:

```
auto someName = createFoo();
plainF(someName.get());
```

Comment: I tell you, don't use naked pointers (yes, you can quote me on that ;) )

Comment: @hellow please read the "Herb" link. It's illuminating. Naked pointers are fine indeed.

Comment: Well, they are fine in a controlled environment where every programmer knows that every programmer knows than a naked pointer means an observer pointer. I'd play safe and use a reference or an optional reference.

Comment: @jimifiki Sure, they are fine, but see `YSC` comment. You can use raw pointers everywhere and do not use smart pointer at all. Why should one, raw pointers are fine, aren't they?

Comment: @YSC: [std::experimental::observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr/observer_ptr) to be sure. :) and *"There are no optional references; a program is ill-formed if it instantiates an optional with a reference type"* :-(

Comment: @hellow IMO smart pointers are precious. And I agree with YSC on raw pointers: "they are fine in a controlled environment".

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm ashamed :/ yes, observer_ptr is nice and all, but it's experimental since the last dinosaur died...

Comment: @Ron: as `void plainf(Foo* f);` doesn't take ownership, you would create memory leak.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) member function which returns a raw pointer to the owned object.

```
plainF(createFoo().get());
```

---

The temporary created by `createFoo()` will not go out of scope until `plainF` has finished. So long as `plainF` doesn't pass the pointer up out of scope this is completely safe.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, thanks! Is it still meaningful to say then that `plainF` has "no claim on the lifetime of Foo", when it's actually responsible for not passing the argument "up out of scope"?

Comment: @lubgr Passing the pointer up is basically playing with the lifetime.  Passing the pointer up out of scope would be extending it's lifetime and since it does not own the pointer it should not be making lifetime decisions on it.

Answer (score 21):

If you don't need the argument to `plainF` to be nullable, you can also change its signature to take the argument by reference, allowing for a slightly less verbose syntax:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> createFoo(); 
void plainf(Foo& f);

plainF(*createFoo());
```

All the lifetime considerations mentioned in [NathanOliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50858292/577603) apply, so this is just as safe to use.

Note that this implies that `createFoo` will never return an empty `unique_ptr`. So if that function is allowed to fail, you must indicate that error through other means, eg. by throwing an exception.

Comment: Assuming you are not terminating the program on a bad allocation, you can't make a `noexcept` factory anyway (outside of some specific cases where you own the memory you allocated from and don't use standard `new`).